# csv uploaded not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am uploading csv file.It is correctly upload in the folder. but data is not displaying when i given echo $row['adv_title'].
this my controller.I want to display the  title

public function upload{

```
 $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH.'/assets/upload/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
$config['max_size']  = '5000';
$replace='"';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->load->database();

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file_name'))
{
    $error=array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_excel','Choose a .csv file to upload'); 
    redirect(base_url().'admin/advertisement/adv');

}
else
{  
   $data=array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
  $userfile=$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
  $upload_data=$this->upload->data(); 
   $this->load->library('csvreader');
   $file=$upload_data['full_path'];
   $file_name=$upload_data['userfile']; 
    $data=$this->csvreader->parse_file($file);
    foreach($data as $row)
{
          echo "hiii".$row['adv_title']; 
}
}
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This -

```
public function upload{

 $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH.'/assets/upload/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
$config['max_size']  = '5000';
$replace='"';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->load->database();

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file_name'))
{
    $error=array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_excel','Choose a .csv file to upload'); 
    redirect(base_url().'admin/advertisement/adv');

}
else
{  
   $data=array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
  $userfile=$data['upload_data']['full_path'];  // file name
  $upload_data=$this->upload->data(); 
  $csv_file = fopen($userfile, "r");
  // it will read csv file and convert into array
   while (($emapData = fgetcsv($csv_file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
     {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($emapData);
     }
  fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: can you modify the code i written.because already i got the answer by using this method.but now i didnt get it

Comment: ya sure jeni please give me some time..i will do it ASAP.