# Csvreader library for Codeigniter not returning all the supposed result of data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using this Csvreader which I just copied. at first it's working fine for less than 10000 lines of records but more than that it seems like the data returned are less than the data that should be returned. And please help for the data are quite important. here's the code..

Please help me solve what's the problem with this code..

```
class Csvreader {

var $fields;            /** columns names retrieved after parsing */ 
var $separator = ';';    /** separator used to explode each line */
var $enclosure = '"';    /** enclosure used to decorate each field */

var $max_row_size = 20000;    /** maximum row size to be used for decoding */

function parse_file($p_Filepath) {

    $file = fopen($p_Filepath, 'r');
    $this->fields = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure);
    $keys_values = explode(',',$this->fields[0]);

    $data_keys = array("column 1", "column 2", "column 3"); /// just improvised

    $content    =   array();
    $keys   =   $data_keys;

    $i  =   1;
    while( ($row = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure)) != false ) {            
        if( $row != null ) { // skip empty lines
            $values =   explode(',',$row[0]);
            if(count($keys) == count($values)){
                $arr    =   array();
                $new_values =   array();
                $new_values =   $this->escape_string($values);
                for($j=0;$j<count($keys);$j++){
                    if($keys[$j] != ""){
                        $arr[$keys[$j]] =   $new_values[$j];
                    }
                }

                $content[$i]=   $arr;
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
    return $content;
    }
}

function escape_string($data){
    $result =   array();
    foreach($data as $row){
        $result[]   =   str_replace('"', '',$row);
    }
    return $result;
}   
}
```

thanks a lot :-)

Comment: do you have error_reporting & display_errors on? - Also I recommend using a real library for that - just because it's tested: https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php

Comment: you have to use this -- Please Try This

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827267/csv-uploaded-not-working/31827388?noredirect=1#comment51591604_31827388

Comment: it's working no errors at all.. it's just that some records are missing.. for example if my csv file has 10,000 lines of records it only returned 9995.. so where did the 5 records went?

Comment: can't you just modify the codes above please?

Comment: There's no error in that code only the returned data.. for example if you upload a csv file with 10,000 lines of records it only returns 9995 so there's five records missing.. can you please modify the codes above please?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and I found the solution in changing the value of the separator

```
var $separator = ';';
```

to be

```
var $separator = '.';
```

But I have to mention that it differs from CSV file to another, as in my system I had to upload two CSV files one for users usage of library books, and the other is for survey result from google forms.
The first file I set the separator to be ";" and it worked just fine, while the second file did not included all file records in the created array till I changed the separator to be dot "."