# How to export excel in PHP and compatible for all devices

Tags: php, codeigniter, export-to-excel

I am trying to export an export file in PHP. I am using Codeigniter Framework.

I exported Excel in this way:

```
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}.xls");
```

It is showing data in Windows in right format. But prompt a message when I initially open it. But When I open it in MAC OS, it is not working.

How can I export Excel in right format that works in Google Drive as well? I have tried so many ways as above and as follows. All not working properly in Mac and Google Drive spreadsheets:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'.xlsx');
header('Content-type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'); 

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'.xls');
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 

header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
```

Comment: Lets start at the beginning, how and in what format are you creating the file you want a user to download. It looks like you have tried a number of formats. **Which one is the file actually in?**

Comment: Actually is xlsx extension and it is not working in windows as well. So please how can ?

Comment: See this it should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566196/phpexcel-to-download

Comment: Please Try This --

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827267/csv-uploaded-not-working/31827388#31827388

Comment: I think none of those are working with Apple Numbers app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you're using codeigniter I would advise you to load a external library to handle your excel stuff.

There's library that everyone uses with PHP called phpspreadsheet.

https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

This will handle all the problems you're having and more. It's really easy to install since its available as a composer package.

https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

Creating a excel file would be as simple as:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
```

And since your using codeigniter you can combine this with the CI download helper to force download the document.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    //ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', '-1');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Registration.xlsx");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
```

Answer (score -2):

header("Content-Type: application/xls");

header("Content-Disposition: attachement; filename=export_test.xls");